# Kivy: How to blick all user interaction?

Tags: python, kivy

**Situation:** Hello, I have a kivy application with buttons/icons which have bindings like changing page, saving/loading data with AWS or local storage, calling an API REST, etc...

**Problem:** Some of theses actions take some time and when I click multiple time on an icon that take time to do an action, my application crash on android.

**Solution:** Every time a binding is called, I disable the possibility of the user to interact with the application and I display a little "charging icon" on the menu.

**Real problem:** I don't know how to do it ! Is there a boolean `userCanInteract` or 2 functions like `enable_user_interaction()` `disable_user_interaction()` ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way to disable all user interaction with your app but you can disable your button like this:

Python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class Window(Widget):
    button = ObjectProperty(None)
    def disable_button(self):
        self.button.disabled = True
        self.button.text = "Disabled"


class GUI(App):
    def build(self):
        return Window()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    GUI().run()
```

.kv file:

```
<Window>
    button: button
    Button:
        id: button
        text: "Enabled"
        disabled: False
        on_release: root.disable_button()
```

For the crashing part, i think using threading module can solve your problem. Every time you click a button for long tasks, create a new thread. Example:

Python:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
import threading
from time import sleep


def do_something(app):
    print("This function is doing something.")
    sleep(1)
    app.root.button.disabled = False
    app.root.button.text = "Enabled"


class Window(Widget):
    button = ObjectProperty(None)

    def disable_button(self, app):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=do_something, args=(app,))
        self.button.disabled = True
        self.button.text = "Disabled"
        thread.start()


class GUI(App):
    def build(self):
        return Window()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    GUI().run()
```

.kv file:

```
<Window>
    button: button
    Button:
        id: button
        text: "Enabled"
        disabled: False
        on_release: root.disable_button(app)
```

This way, your button will be disabled until the thread is done. When the thread ends, button will be enabled.

Comment: Thank you for the answer,, however I won't use thread, I prefer to freeze the app (I did in the past but I always finish with too much complexity for basic stuff.
And for the ```disable```, that's what I want but I will have to create custom buttons/icons that all refer to a global variable and they will always watch this one before doing anything, I wanted to know if kivy already had this.